# how to deal with a SSIS 2005 validation error in a script component

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

Within a script component, a strange error occurs.

- the (vb.net) code leads to `build succeeded`
- as mentioned, build done

BUT and that's not really awesome  (and, yes, design script was clicked):

> Error 1   Validation error. Load Observations: Script Load into
>   MeasuringParameters & Observations [194]: The script component is
>   configured to pre-compile the script, but binary code is not found.
>   Please visit the IDE in Script Component Editor by clicking Design
>   Script button to cause binary code to be
>   generated.    LoadTransMeas.dtsx  0   0

any hints how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2005 RTM?

Comment: afaik no, it is SQL Server 9.0.5057

Comment: Does this article cover your issue? [KB932556](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932556)

Comment: huh ... currently, downloading the server update .....

Comment: the server number above was wrong cause it was my local server and the sql server within a vm is used (build nr<1500). hence, the wrong hotfix was installed & the correct hotfix was not able to install due to my fault. however, now it works. (and the sql server in the vm will be reinstalled anyway which has no relation with the wrong hotfix). thanks a lot. you could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with 2005, there were some known issues with scripts.

For the reported version of 9.0.5057, you'd want to look at [KB932556](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932556)

Earlier version (RTM) of SQL Server would have [KB932557](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932557) applied